# How to rewrite the simple iterable class from JavaScript to TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I wrote the simple iterable class on JavaScript ES6:

```js
// JavaScript ES6
class FooIterable {
 
 constructor(items){
  this.data = items; 
 }
 
 *[Symbol.iterator](){
  for(let n of this.data){
   yield n;
  }
 }
}

const foo = new FooIterable(['Bob','John','Mark']);

for(let n of foo) console.log(n);
```

Now I want to write the same on TypeScript 2.6. This is my attempt:

```
class FooIterable {

    data: string[];

    constructor(items : string[]){
        this.data = items; 
    }

    *[Symbol.iterator](){
        for(let n of this.data){
            yield n;
        }
    }
}
const foo = new FooIterable(['Bob', 'John', 'Mark']);
for(let n of foo) console.log(n);
```

But I see such error in the online editor:

[image]

How can I do what I need?

Comment: This should work if the typescript target is es6 or higher. What is your target listed as in your tsconfig file? Per Explosion Pills' answer, it will also work with the `downlevelIteration` flag for targets lower than es6, but be aware there is a performance cost for that downleveling.

Comment: @CRice `es6` in `tsconfig`

Answer (score 3):

Using iterators requires the [`downlevelIteration` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html). I don't see where this option is exposed in the playground, unfortunately.

As an alternative, you could use `Array.from` since that will convert it to an array type that can be used, and `.from` will use the iterator internally as well.

```
for (let n of Array.from(foo))
```

NOTE: for an target that supports this iteration natively (such as es6) you don't need the `downlevelIteration` option.